# Jumbling array elements

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program that has an array of String `String options[4]`, which holds the four options for a question. One answer is correct of these. By the logic of my program, the program places the correct answer at `options[0]`, and randomly chooses any three other names from the database and places them at `options[1]`, `[2]` and `[3]`.

I tried to change the logic of placing the options in the array itself, but that is complicating my program, so choosing not to do so. I also tried to use random function to swap two locations, but as i'm coding this in android java, its taking too mch time, and by default, the android os stops responding if the random function takes too much time. so as far as possible, i dont wanna use a random function. is there any other logic or readymade function available to jumble an array??
I require a code that randomly jumbles the four options in the array as below:

```
String options[] = new String[4];
options[0]="Correct Answer";
options[1]="Wrong Answer 1";
options[2]="Wrong Answer 2";
options[3]="Wrong Answer 3";
//here i want the code to jumble
```

Please provide the code..
Thanks a ton.

Comment: What is this C#, Java ??

Answer (score 3):

It's simple:

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(yourArray));
```

`Arrays.asList()` provides a `List` backed by the supplied array, so when the `List` is shuffled, so is the underlying (original) array.

See:

- [`Collections.shuffle(list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)
- [`Arrays.asList(array)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle):

```
Random r = new Random();
for(int i = options.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
    int rand = r.nextInt(i);
    String temp = options[i];
    options[i] = options[rand];
    options[rand] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**: As mentioned in the comments, ignore this solution and use the solutions provided above.

Since you have defined `options` as `String options[]`, I assume you're coding in Java. So here is the jumble code in Java:

```
    String options[] = new String[4];
    options[0]="Correct Answer";
    options[1]="Wrong Answer 1";
    options[2]="Wrong Answer 2";
    options[3]="Wrong Answer 3";

    final int jumbleTries = 100;
    Random rand = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i < jumbleTries; i++)
    {

        int index1 = rand.nextInt(options.length);
        int index2 = rand.nextInt(options.length);

        if (index1 == index2)
            continue;

        String temp = options[index1];
        options[index1] = options[index2];
        options[index2] = temp;
    }
```

Comment: hey thank a lot... but i've tried this, but it takes a lot of time, as i'm coding this java in android version. If if takes too much time, then the android os will assume the app is not responding and shoot an error. is there any built in random function?? i mean, i saw one that does "collection.jumble()" but dint fully understand it. so can you please give me any faster solution to this?? as far as possible avoiding random function...

Comment: this is a very poor shuffling algorithm.  Look up "Fisher Yates".

Comment: This method is incredibly computationally expensive, just use the java.util.Collections shuffle method as mre demonstrated.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `shuffle` method in Java. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: can you please give an example code as to how to use a Collection shuffle function in my code?? i tried, but not able to compile, and many exapmles dont show how it works... thanx

Comment: @Gaurav See the answer above mine.